# props not defined in render but value seen in return of render for the first time component is mounted

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am using React with react-router and react-redux. 
When a component mounts I do dispatch to get data from database. 
My Parent Component has this

```
const TopComp = React.createClass({  
 componentWillMount(){
     this.props.dispatch(getData(this.params.id))
 },
 render() {
  <ChildComp data={this.props.data} />
 }
})
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {data:state.data}
 }
export default connect()(TopComp)
```

My Child Component Looks like this:

```
 const ChildComp = React.createClass({
 getInitialState() {
  console.log(this.props.data) 
 //empty for the first time but gets data other times
 }
 render(){
 console.log(this.props.data) //prints undefined
 return(
  {this.props.data} //gives the data
 ) 
 }
 })
```

Also my TopComp Updates with click on the links on it's parent component. It receives different params.id and fetches data for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing your `mapStateToProps` function to connect...so I am surprised you are even getting access to your state data at all.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TopComp)
```

as for this.props.data printing undefined --> you are only fetching data when the parent component mounts - this then does an XHR request etc so at first this.props.data in the child component will be undefined because the request has not completed yet.

Comment: actually i missed the mapStateToProps while I was typing in here. I surely facing the issue that you mentioned that component doesn't receive the props in initial render() . Can you tell me how can this be done in a different way so I will get the props in initial render in the Child